# DBError and Network Error when saving phone numbers to contacts

Tags: contacts, phone

In our organization's new civi database, we are unable to add phone numbers to contacts. I've tried keying in the number and importing a contact with a number. (It took me hours to figure out that it was the phone numbers that were breaking the import!)

There are two error messages we get, depending on the context:

In the View Contact view of the data, when I try to save a phone number, we get this error message:

> Network Error
>
> Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser
>   and try again.

In the Edit Contact view, or when trying to import a record with a phone number, we get this error message:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
>
> DB Error: unknown error
>   Return to home page.

Log is below, and seems to suggest it has something to do with stripping non-integer characters from the field. However, adding a phone number without any dashes 5554443333 also produces the error. Any ideas?

> Jul 02 12:28:40  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
>   (
>       [callback] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => CRM_Core_Error
>               [1] => handle
>           )
>
> ```
> [code] => -1
> [message] => DB Error: unknown error
> [mode] => 16
> [debug_info] => 
> CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8)
>   RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8
>   DETERMINISTIC
>   NO SQL
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE output   VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '';
>   DECLARE iterator INT          DEFAULT 1;
>   WHILE iterator < (LENGTH(input) + 1) DO
>     IF SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1) IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9') THEN
>       SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1));
>     END IF;
>     SET iterator = iterator + 1;
>   END WHILE;
>   RETURN output;
> END [nativecode=1419 ** You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)]
> [type] => DB_Error
> [user_info] => 
> CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8)
>   RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8
>   DETERMINISTIC
>   NO SQL
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE output   VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '';
>   DECLARE iterator INT          DEFAULT 1;
>   WHILE iterator < (LENGTH(input) + 1) DO
>     IF SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1) IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9') THEN
>       SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1));
>     END IF;
>     SET iterator = iterator + 1;
>   END WHILE;
>   RETURN output;
> END [nativecode=1419 ** You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)]
> [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="
> CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8)
>   RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8
>   DETERMINISTIC
>   NO SQL
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE output   VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '';
>   DECLARE iterator INT          DEFAULT 1;
>   WHILE iterator < (LENGTH(input) + 1) DO
>     IF SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1) IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9') THEN
>       SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1));
>     END IF;
>     SET iterator = iterator + 1;
>   END WHILE;
>   RETURN output;
> END [nativecode=1419 ** You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)]"]
> ```
>
> )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was, but it seems to have related to our host. We've switched hosts and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your error log says:

> ** You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)]

If you turn off logging at **Administer > System settings > Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.)**  can you save phone numbers?

You can find information on the MySQL privileges needed for CiviCRM at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+MySQL+Permission+Requirements

Not all hosting companies provide these privileges without a specific request to do so (and even then some will refuse to do so).

Comment: Not sure why it says binary logging is enabled, because it is not, according to the misc settings panel. This log is from an instance when I had turned debugging on. Does that automatically enable binary logging? Even if it does, the phone number problem was occurring before that.

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours trying to fix this probably-same problem.  I could edit other contact fields, but phone number always choked.

What finally fixed it for me:

> $ mysql_upgrade -u root -p

The key clue was a mention of "mysql.proc" in a backtrace, which led to a mysql forum.  Apparently, you're supposed to run that command whenever you upgrade mysql.

Comment: Don't know if that would have solved my problem, since our server change fixed it, but thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

For Joomla users, the file located at
`/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php` requires a semicolon at line 42:

```
const DROP_STRIP_FUNCTION_43 = "DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS civicrm_strip_non_numeric;";
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, caused when DreamHost upgraded from MySQL 5.7 to 8.  Trigger functions aren't supported anymore unless you pay an extra $15/mo for MySQL VPS. For details on my problem see: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/75p1thb8w3fq9gx9rwsirphy6a
I'm going to look into CiviHosting.com