# Phonenumber error Joomla 3.4.8 civicrm 4.6.11

Tags: contacts, joomla, error

I got an error in Joomla 3.4.8 Civicrm 4.6.11. When I try to save contacts with a phone number it says:

```
NETWORK ERROR Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.
```

Without phone number working. When I write "what so ever" in phonenumber it be error. Trying all kind of phonenumbers us and eu number only numbers and +46 in still results in this error.

Separately, on the same instance, when creating a contact from start it I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

Although this error does not appear when I save it without a phonenumber.

Is there an easy fix to this?

Kind Regards

Thomas Rosenhoff

Comment: Have you tried to replicate this problem on the demo CiviCRM site? This will help you to determine if this is indeed a specific CiviCRM bug or if this is something with your specific installation.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not an intermittent problem that has gone away by now, then likely your installation or upgrade has caused some problems. My guess is that you need to check the base_url in your civicrm.settings.php file, or more properly, in the CiviCRM Resource URL field under Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I first set up our Civi. [Here's my question.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/dberror-and-network-error-when-saving-phone-numbers-to-contacts) I didn't get much response to it, and we ended up changing hosting servers, and on the new server I didn't have the same problem. Which means, I didn't get to try out the one answer to my question that may have solved it, but you can try it!